# go on an exchange program to US

Tags: syntax

> Last year, he **went on** a foreign exchange program **to** the US.

I am quite confident that the sentence above is perfectly natural as I found several similar sentences in the COCA(Corpus of contemporary American English). However, I am not so sure whether these sound natural as well.

> ... he **went to** the US **as** a foreign exchange student.

or

> ... he **went to** the US **for** a foreign exchange program.

or

> ... he **went to** the US **to join** a foreign exchange program.

As regards the words marked in bold, which one sounds more natural to you?

Comment: The first one, or "*... he went to the US **on** a foreign exchange program.*"

Answer (score 1):

The first one is fine. The other two read a little oddly, because the exchange would have had to be arranged *before* he travelled, so he didn't go to the US *to join* the scheme.

Comment: Exactly, The foreign exchange program is the **mechanism**, not the **objective**.